# "I've seen all of Tarantino's films" vs "I've seen all Tarantino's films"

Tags: pronouns

I encountered the sentence "I've seen all Tarantino's films" in a book I was reading. I found the writing odd since I would normally write it as "I've seen all of Tarantino's films" (because I've heard people say it this way).
I looked into the different use of "all/all of" but only undertood explainations for when you use pronouns.
Can anyone explain if the use is correct, incorrect, or optional and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, we always use **all of** when it's followed by a pronoun:

> Yes, I've seen all of them
>   I've seen all of his books
>   Can you fit all of us in your car?

The **of** is optional when it's followed by a noun, for example

> I want all [of] the news about your wedding
>   The dog ate all [of] the food

For a small number of the words, it is never used:

> I waited all day for him

Comment: Nothing wrong, in my opinion, with JavaLatte's answer, which is what I would have given.

Comment: So what is it for Tarantino's films? Tarantino's isn't a pronoun.

Comment: @stackzebra: If it's not followed by a pronoun, the **of** is optional.